# iOS Swift, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, apple-push-notifications

I need to check whether the user has granted the permission for Notification or not, till date i knew that `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` gets called only when the notification permission is given, but in some devices its getting called irrespective of the permission given or not. Can someone help me out as to how to check the status of permission.

> `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` is getting called even when i deny the permission for notification access.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3.0 and Xcode 8

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .sound, .alert], completionHandler: { (granted, error) in
                            if (granted)
                            {
                                UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                                //Allow Push Notification

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //Don't Allow Push Notification
                            }
                        })
```